# Display alert when settings bundle switch is toggled

Tags: iphone, uialertview, application-settings

I want to show an alert when i toggle the switch of the iPhone application settings bundle. Can anyone please help me out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When a switch in Settings.app is toggled, your app is in the background. However, [if you would have read the Developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_71) you would have seen that there is a `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` available that you can subscribe to and show your alert when the app is back in the foreground.

Reading the documentation and showing a little more research effort really helps, it's what developers do every day.

Comment: Hi David i want to show the alert in the settings screen itself like an action sheet is displayed in safari settings when clear history is clicked.

Comment: That won't happen. `MobileSettings.app` is a separate application, with some of its settings powered by Settings bundles. The Safari pane has been created programmatically, hence the dialog. You **cannot** replicate that.